# Symfony2 XmlHttpRequest file upload issue. Form model's file property not being set

Tags: ajax, symfony, symfony-forms

Have a form that uploads files using Ajax. (drop-zone up-loader)

Made a form type with fields:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add("file", "file");
    $builder->add("submit", "submit");
}
```

The model class looks like:

```
class DropzoneFileModel {

     /**
     *
     * @var UploadedFile
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="4096k")
     */
    protected $file;

    /**
     *
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    ..
}
```

**Problem:**

- When the request is NOT made through Ajax the model object's $file property has the uploaded file

  ```
  $formModel->getFile() == UploadedFile
  $request->files->get("file") == null
  ```
- When the request IS a XmlHttpRequest the $file property is not set, but the file stays in the $request->files collection.

  ```
  $formModel->getFile() == null
  $request->files->get("file") == UploadedFile
  ```

I am not able to upload file. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You should also paste your JavaScript code that uploads the file.

Comment: Is $_FILES filled at the ajax-request? If not, it's the fault of the client/javascript.

Comment: The http://www.dropzonejs.com/ jQuery library handles the javascript part.  The request headers are almost identical. The only difference is that the Ajax request has **Accept:application/json** and additionaly **X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest**

What is weird is that the file is transferred but depending on the request type it gets injected into the model object and removed from the $request->files collection (normal request), or it gets not injected into the model object and is available in the $request->files collection (Ajax)

Comment: (I see comments are not being formatted.)  Yes, as described in the question, and verified now, $_FILES is being filled. The problem is with Symfony's request handling depending on the request type.

Comment: Good startpoint for debugging is to place a brakepoint at vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php:231 and look at the backtrace to see why it is not filled.